readonly with multiple nested conditionals
can someone help me please, in Odoo 16 I need to do a readonly with some complicated conditions, it would be this:
readonly if (v1=A and (v3=X or v3=Y)) or (v1!=A and v2!=B and (v3=X or v3=Y or v3=Z))

I have this code but it gives me an error:
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError, Error while validating view near

The xml code for the field is
<field name="campo" attrs="{  
  'readonly': [  
    '|',
    (
      ('v1', '=', 'A'), 
      '|',
      ('v3', '=', 'X'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Y'), 
    ),
    (
      ('v1', '!=', 'A'), 
      ('v2', '!=', 'B'), 
      '|',
      '|',
      ('v3', '=', 'X'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Y'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Z'), 
    )
  ]  
}"/>


In odoo, nested conditions can not be built using parenthesis: (A | B) & (C | D) but this way &,|,A,B,|,C,D: beginning from the inner-details (2 by 2), and then, step by step, to the outer-most conditions following a "left-to-right writing" order:

<field name="campo" attrs="{  
  'readonly': [  
   '|',
      '&',
        ('v1', '=', 'A'), 
        '|',('v3', '=', 'X'),('v3', '=', 'Y'),  
      '&',
         '&',('v1', '!=', 'A'),('v2', '!=', 'B'), 
         '|','|',('v3', '=', 'X'),('v3', '=', 'Y'),('v3', '=', 'Z') 
    
  ]  
}"/>


I have used line-breaks for clarity... if it causes error, try without:
<field name="campo" attrs="{'readonly': ['|','&',('v1', '=', 'A'),'|',('v3', '=', 'X'),('v3', '=', 'Y'),'&','&',('v1', '!=', 'A'),('v2', '!=', 'B'),'|','|',('v3', '=', 'X'),('v3', '=', 'Y'),('v3', '=', 'Z')]  }"/>

